# How to build a flow that doesn't restart between collections

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

How to build a flow that doesn't restart/reset between terminal operation (eg: `collect`):

```kotlin
fun <T> Flow<T>.asResumableFlow(): Flow<T> = ???

// Usage
val flow = flowOf(1, 2).asResumableFlow()
flow.first() // 1
flow.first() // 2, not 1
flow.firstOrNull() // null
```

I have a flow must be collected multiple times because it is collected in a loop over another logic:

```kotlin
val resumableFlow: Flow<Expensive> = ...

while (condition) {
  if (mainTaskSucceded) continue
  fallback(resumableFlow.first()) // Only produce Expensive when needed
}
```

In most case no fallback will be needed, so it is important that no value is computed until actually needed.

Constraints:

- no value shall be computed until actually needed
- no value shall be lost between consumer
- no value shall be sent to multiple consumer
- when a consumer detaches, no value is computed until another one attaches
- when the producer flow ends, consumer flow must also end. Any new consumer will receive an empty flow.

Non constraints:

- no consumer overlap. there will only every be one collector at a time

I haven't found how Channel, StateFlow and MutableFlow could avoid violating those constraints, especially about not computing a value until needed.

They all have a push model, where my problem is better expressed as a pull. Cold flow match the pull model (started on demand), except for the reset on restart.

My current workaround is to save the flow state in an persistent object. When the flow is restarted, it resume where it was left:

```kotlin
fun resumableFlow(): Flow<Expensive> {
  val state = State()
  return flow {
     while (state.hasNext()) {
       emit(state.next())
     }
  }
}
```

This is far from ideal as the state machine is manual, the opposite of what coroutines normally allow.

Here is a draft `asResumableFlow`:

```
public fun <T> Flow<T>.asResumableFlow(
    context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext
): Flow<T> = ResumableFlow(this, context)

public class ResumableFlow<T>(flow: Flow<T>, context: CoroutineContext) : Flow<T> {
    /** Resume to produce a new value from `flow`. `null` when `flow` ended. */
    private var collect: Continuation<Unit>? = createCollectCoroutine(flow, context)

    /** Set each time `flow` produces a value. `null` when `flow` ended. */
    private var value: T? = null

    /** Set if `flow` ended in failure, `null` otherwise. */
    private var throwable: Throwable? = null

    private fun createCollectCoroutine(flow: Flow<T>, context: CoroutineContext): Continuation<Unit> {
        val finishContinuation = Continuation<Unit>(context) {
            collect = null
            value = null
            throwable = it.exceptionOrNull()
        }
        return suspend { suspendCollect(flow) }.createCoroutine(finishContinuation)
    }

    /** Collect [flow], suspending after each value is received. */
    private suspend fun suspendCollect(flow: Flow<T>) {
        flow.collect { value ->
            this.value = value
            suspendCoroutine {
                collect = it
            }
        }
    }

    private fun resumeCollect(): Boolean {
        collect?.resume(Unit)
        return collect != null
    }

    override suspend fun collect(collector: FlowCollector<T>) {
        flow<T> {
            while (resumeCollect()) {
                emit(value!!)
            }
            throwable?.let { throw it }
        }.collect(collector)
    }
}
```

It works but it feels hacky given its low level.

Comment: Try to use Channel

Comment: Read up on SharedFlow. You do need a hot flow if you want to support resuming, even if there is only one collector at a time. By definition the ability to resume instead of restarting makes it hot.   Your hack above is effectively a complicated hot flow with some features disabled. But yes, Channel is possibly the more appropriate solution depending on what exactly you’re doing.

Comment: Shared flow never stop and produce values without consumer. Both things undesirable for my design.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of flows: *cold* flows and *hot* flows. Regular flows generated by `flowOf()`, for example, are *cold*. That means they are only activated when `collect` (or any other terminal operator) is applied. That also means that the flow is recreated from scratch each time, so each collector receives values independent of other collectors.

*Hot* flows on the other hand run independent of the collectors. That means when a new collector subscribes to the flow, it receives the value that is already there and continues with the values that are emitted from then on. That also means that multiple collectors receive the same values, they share the flow. *Hot* flows are usually of type `SharedFlow` or are of a subtype like `StateFlow`.

You can create such a *hot* flow with `MutableSharedFlow()` or `MutableStateFlow()`. You can also easily turn an already existing *cold* flow into a *hot* flow by calling `shareIn()` respectively `stateIn()`. There are several ways to configure a *hot* flow to pause when there are no collectors, to buffer a certain amount of values, to replay old values to new collectors, to skip same values and so on.

Most use cases can be realized by a properly configured shared flow. One thing to note, though: Flows decide themselves when to generate new values, even *cold* flows. You can collect those values if you are interested in them, but flows are not designed to only produce values one after another, when a collector requests the next one. So your example with calling `first()` twice (as in, *give me the first value, then give me the second value*) isn't how flows behave in general. You usually would have a collector with a lambda instead that is called each time a new value is available. When and where you process the values is then up to you.

If you really need to request one value at a time you should use a `Channel` instead of a flow. Channels provide a more primitive, low-level API that flows use themselves under the hood.

You can read more about the differences of Channels and Flows and when to use what here: https://elizarov.medium.com/shared-flows-broadcast-channels-899b675e805c

Comment: I looked into channel and hot flow, but could not figure out how to avoid computing a value until needed. Even if the channel has no buffer, it will still prepare a value, then block until the consumer receives it. Could you add an example?

Comment: I've clarified my constraints in the question. After double checking on the different resources provided, I really don't see how your suggestions of Channel and shared flow match my needs.